# Parameter estimation after model selection

Tags: estimation, modeling, model-selection, aic

The field of model selection is well known - e.g. AIC, BIC, MDL and such.
However, I cannot find what people do after the modeling part is done, i.e. once I've chosen a specific model for my set, I need to estimate the model's parameters, don't I?

In most model selection criteria, Maximum Likelihood estimation of the parameters is a preliminary stage to the selection, but yet - no one says that he uses that estimation in the following stages.

An academic valid reference is preferred, however not obligatory.

Comment: The sequence of action is normally the opposite to what you say: first you estimate the different models and only then you compare them and choose one of them. You do not need to estimate the chosen one anew as it has already been estimated before th model selection stage. (However, if you are using cross validation for model selection, then once a model has been selected you would estimate it on the whole sample rather than just the training sample).

Comment: Thanks @RichardHardy. Of course you are right - in order to select a model using some information criterion, an MLE is required. It's just not clear in the literature whether you use the same estimation as your final parameter. If so - can you point out an article\book that speaks of this procedure?

Comment: I don't have a reference, but a thought has never occurred to me to reestimate the model with some other technique than used for model comparison. I have not seen anyone do this. Of course, if we split our sample into training, validation and possibly test, then the final model should be estimated on a appropriate subsample (training + validation for assessing performance on the test set, or full sample for actual use in the field), but the same estimation technique would be used as for estimation on the training sample.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition regarding the optimality of standard maximum likelihood estimators post-selection is correct. The `true' maximum likelihood estimator of a selected model is the conditional maximum likelihood estimator:

[Tractable Post-Selection Maximum Likelihood Inference for the Lasso | arXivLabs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09417)

[Post-selection estimation and testing following aggregated association tests
| arXivLabs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00497)

Also, standard tests are invalid:

[Exact post-selection inference, with application to the lasso
| arXivLabs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6238)

[Recent Advances in Post-Selection Statistical Inference | Robert Tibshirani, Stanford University](http://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/ftp/nips2015.pdf)

Comment: I came across these suggestions, of a conditional ML, however it seems.... like it was cheating. In order to achieve optimality, I could only condition on the knowledge of the true generating model, therefore the problem of model selection is practically not existing.

Comment: When computing the conditional maximum likelihood estimator, you condition on the selection of the model that was selected in practice: not necessarily the one that generated the data. In fact, the data generating distribution is not assumed to be in the family of models under consideration. The consistency statements are for the parameter values that minimize the KL divergence between the selected model and the data generating distribution.